# CodeIgniter env based MY_ class extensions

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm working on a CodeIgniter 3.1.4 project and am aware that I can use `MY_` prefixed library classes to extend the system libraries.

This is great and works as expected, but I'd like to be able to determine the class being used dependant on either the current environment, or by DotEnv values *(I've already got a DotEnv library working fine)*.

The production site uses the servers 'sendmail' to send email, I would like to be able to use MailGun (or another) in development, allowing me to overriding the `'to'` value just before sending to allow for safe development utilising a production like dataset.

*Much like is able to be done in Laravel where you can use `.env`'s `MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun` and `MAIL_TO_ADDRESS=x@y.com` to force all outbound mail to one address for development.*

I'm sure it must be possible, but my lack of experience with CI and where I should be implementing this into the framework is letting me down.

Comment: I'd suggest reading https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/environments.html and https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html#environments

Comment: Thanks - I've been through both of those, which only outline how you can specify different configurations based on the environments... I need to be able to dynamically override the core system libraries based on the environment, not load different ones...
CI forces that you use MY_ based file/class names to override base ones, and I cant figure out how to only dynamically load those based on env... as their presense alone in the directory forces the overload. =(

Comment: but inside MY_ you can check which environment you have and create 2 different configs for your email

Comment: I thought about that - in using the `MY_Email.php` class to be a factory for the actual real class needed behind the scenes based on the `env` defined service - but you cant have two MY classes overriding the Email one - so you'd have one MASSIVE MY_Email class with switches for each service... feels nasty

Comment: do the 2 different setups for your email in config/email.php

Comment: Hmm, I think I'm missing something... as I dont believe you can change the implementation of the mail sending class within config - only utilise the in built functionality.

I need to override quite a lot of the methods from CI_Email to make MailGun work... and the config does not allow this.

Comment: in config/email.php you set the host, password, protocol, etc., so either mailgun or sendmail. of course you still need to in My_email check the environment to manage the email_to, etc. I'd solve it this way, maybe not the nicest, but just one if/else clause

Comment: I'm using the API for MailGun, so the current CI_Email class doesn't cater for it... the class methods must be extended with new functionality. What then happens when I want to implement more mail sending interfaces? Just seems Im struggling quite hard to implement standard interface level classes... it cant be this hard in CI?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually in the links that Vickel sent. You can override your configuration files *per domain/environment* and you can therefore change the MY_ prefix to YOUR_ prefix in the different config.php file.

How you do this (quoted but tweaked):

> Create the directory application/config/not_my_environment/
>
> Copy your existing config.php into the above directory
>
> Edit application/config/not_my_environment/config.php so it contains your production settings

Set the ENVIRONMENT constant based on an htaccess SetEnv variable (I have just posted a very similar answer here: [Maintain the same project within multiple sub-domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349433/maintain-the-same-project-within-multiple-sub-domains)) which then allows you to vary your files per domain.

Once you are running off a custom per-deployment set of configuration files you can set the prefix to be whatever you like and therefore have multiple MY_, YOUR_, ANY_ prefix based classes override the CI defaults.