# Maintain the same project within multiple sub-domains

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, subdomain

I'm facing a situation and I'd like to have some feedback/guidance about the best approach.

I have a big project developed with PHP and CodeIgniter working as a SaaS solution for more than a year and it's working perfectly. A new client about two months ago asked me if he can use my software but with some new features developed specifically for him. I said yes and created a sub-domain with the base structure of my main project along with the new developments he asked for.

What happens is that now other client asked me the same and whenever I find a bug within the main project I have to go to both sub-domains projects and fix. If the bug involves several files..this is taking me too much time and it may create some errors.

So, what I'm asking here is if there's any better solution than copy-all-files from main project when creating a sub-domain for a specific client?

I thought about this:

1. Only create the new files / fixed files with new features in the sub-domain with the correct file structure of the main project.
2. Somehow with .htaccess "redirect" to the files from subdomain if they exist?

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Are you using a VCS like git?

Comment: @Devon I use git but only in a personal mode. Whenever I change something I commit in order to have a history of the changes.

Comment: This may be a good use case for a git fork

Comment: @Devon How so? My goal is to stop clone my base project

Comment: Well, that's your XY problem solution of this, but I don't think that's an ideal solution.  Unless you have an extensive plugin system built for this,  I think a git fork, or a separate branch, is the best way to handle this.  You can create bug fixes on your master branch and merge them to any of your other branches or forks.  If there are any conflicts, you'll have to fix them, but if the code in the affected files are the same, the changes will be auto-merged.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible... But defnitive in more than one way.

One Option is to use a VCS like GIT and push changes to a master branch if it affects core modules and then merge the commit into all other special branches. But this involves still the same files in different locations on the server.

You could also think about refactoring your project and build a core module, that is used in every project and implement some kind of module system, so that the custom modules are as pluggable as possible. Then you could import the core modules from one central location and only the specific modifications for each customer are on different locations.

But the decision for one of the solutions is higly dependend on your project structure and how the custom parts of the customers are affecting the other modules and functions.

Comment: So the solution of the user login in the sub-domain and then the `.htaccess` tells the user if some URL should be readed on the main-domain or sub-domain is not possible?

Comment: As far as I know .htaccess used in combination with apache web server only gives you the ability to rewrite and redirect requests. If you do so, your user would be logged out, if an request to your parent site is made, because your session is only valid for your subdomain.

Comment: And if you are using a database to store the customer data, there would be also a problem accessing the right database. If your subdomain just redirects to your main project, how do you make sure to write in the database for that subdomain and not for the main project.

Comment: The database ain't no problem, because my project already works with multi-database system, every subscriptions has its own database.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want 1 source code but output in 2 different domains. This is something I've done with Codeigniter and relies on a little feature of the htaccess in that you can set PHP environment variables from with the htaccess. This is useful because in Codeigniter you can then vary paths to different views or config files dependent on if the variable is present.

You will need separate views, config, language packs and routes but this is definitely possible. For example in your htaccess:

`SetEnv SITE_NAME "test.co.uk"`

You will then need to set different elements:

1. In the index.php (which can vary per version) switch the URL dependent on the `SITE_NAME` variable
2. In the index.php change the view folder (to your version specific views)
3. Change your config variables using the ENVIRONMENT settings as per the manual here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html

This will allow you to run one set of code but with 2 front ends.

Comment: Hey Antony, please take a look at this https://pastebin.com/AnvmJM0c, do you think the environment variables would work like this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. 1 option is to differentiate the routes - but this still leaves all the files in the same folder. 2. Would be to differentiate the whole application folder but this would require duplicates of your Home or Customers controller. Bearing in mind this may become unworkable (as you'll have to maintain multiple copies of the same files) I think a better solution is to create different database tables and change the tables in a single model rather than trying to differentiate the Controllers. If you must, then I would advise a folder like controllers/NAME/backend/Report.php etc